# RMI replicated Ehcache does not working

Tags: java, websphere, ehcache, multicast, distributed-caching

I'm using RMI replicated Ehcache 2.6.3 on WebSphere 8.

After application get started getting this error message from ehcache.

**(PayloadUtil.java:203)  Could not ungzip. Heartbeat will not be working. Not in GZIP format**

What could be the reason?

Here is the configuration:

```
<cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties=""/>
    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
            properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                        multicastGroupAddress=239.21.131.242,
                        multicastGroupPort=${multicastGroupPort}, timeToLive=32"
            propertySeparator="," />
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory" />

<cache name="REFERENCE_DATA"
           maxElementsInMemory="1000"
           eternal="false"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           statistics="true"
           timeToLiveSeconds="10800"
            >
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
                properties="replicateAsynchronously=false, replicatePuts=false,
                            replicatePutsViaCopy=false, replicateUpdates=true,
                            replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true"/>            
    </cache>



2013-02-15 09:30:45,903 DEBUG (RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:548)  4 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
2013-02-15 09:30:45,904 DEBUG (ConfigurationHelper.java:325)  CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE'.
2013-02-15 09:30:45,905 DEBUG (ConfigurationHelper.java:354)  CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE'.
2013-02-15 09:30:45,906 DEBUG (MemoryStore.java:149)  Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.NotifyingMemoryStore for ERROR_CODES_CACHE
2013-02-15 09:30:45,907 DEBUG (Cache.java:1164)  Initialised cache: ERROR_CODES_CACHE
2013-02-15 09:30:45,908 DEBUG (RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:516)  Adding to RMI listener
2013-02-15 09:30:45,911 DEBUG (RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:548)  5 RMICachePeers bound in registry for RMI listener
2013-02-15 09:30:45,912 DEBUG (ConfigurationHelper.java:325)  CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'ERROR_CODES_CACHE'.
2013-02-15 09:30:45,912 DEBUG (ConfigurationHelper.java:354)  CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'ERROR_CODES_CACHE'.
2013-02-15 09:30:47,588 INFO  (CacheFactory.java:29)  ERROR_CODES_CACHE : Cache is defined as "load on demand"
2013-02-15 09:30:47,588 INFO  (CacheFactory.java:25)  CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE loading
2013-02-15 09:30:47,592 INFO  (CacheFactory.java:27)  CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE loaded
2013-02-15 09:30:47,592 INFO  (CacheFactory.java:25)  REFERENCE_DATA loading
2013-02-15 09:30:47,593 DEBUG (Cache.java:1969)  Cache: CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE store hit for environmentconfig
2013-02-15 09:30:47,939 INFO  (CacheFactory.java:27)  REFERENCE_DATA loaded
2013-02-15 09:30:50,780 DEBUG (PayloadUtil.java:153)  Cache peers for this CacheManager to be advertised: //172.21.131.242:50551/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:50551/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:50551/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:50551/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:50551/REFERENCE_DATA
2013-02-15 09:30:50,781 ERROR (PayloadUtil.java:203)  Could not ungzip. Heartbeat will not be working. Not in GZIP format
2013-02-15 09:30:50,782 DEBUG (MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver.java:148)  rmiUrls received
```

Comment: Same error [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/glassfish#payloadutil-reports-could-not-ungzip-heartbeat-will-not-be-working-not-in-gzip-format) and [here](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-5485), in both cases the problem was multicast address and port. Probable either WAS or some other system is cross talking to EhCache unintentionally via multicast. Have you tried changing multicast address, port?

Comment: Yes i tried to change both multicast address and port, but getting the same error message.